# Determine if a script is running in Windows or Linux

Tags: r, multiplatform

Is there a simple way to programmatically determine if an R script is being executed in Windows vs. Linux?

Comment: I am a little late to this party but consider this Google Code Search:  http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=linux+windows&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_lang=r -- i.e. specify 'as_lang=r' to get R-based solutions only when looking for strings 'linux' and 'windows'.  And it's right there....

Comment: fantastic! I didn't know about the GOOG code search. I struggled and struggled to search for this but kept getting unrelated results.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
} else {

}
```

Comment: i shouldn't have wasted that time with the first comment. Beaten to the punch again.

Comment: If it had been a useful comment, I would be sympathetic... But that one was really wasted time! :)

Comment: Thanks! I could not remember this to save my life.

Comment: actually this returns 'unix' on OSX also.  I guess you'd need to also check `Sys.info()["sysname"]=='Darwin'` to distinguish.

Answer (score 20):

```
Sys.info()["sysname"]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
.Platform$OS.type
```

returns

```
[1] "unix"
```

or something else.

Comment: See also R.version() for other OS-type things.

Comment: ahh.. capitalization. It's R.Version()

Answer (score 13):

I run the same code from any of three Linux or Windows machines. I use the following to set up working directories:

```
if(R.Version()$os == "linux-gnu"){
  dir.pre <- "/home"
} else {
  dir.pre <- "C:/Users"
}
```

On my debian linux server and my Ubuntu laptop:

```
> .Platform$OS.type
[1] "unix"
> R.Version()$os
[1] "linux-gnu"
```

On my Windows 10 laptop, in RStudio:

```
> .Platform$OS.type
[1] "windows"
> R.Version()$os
[1] "mingw32"
```

Feel free to edit and add to this list.