# How to check the OS within R

Tags: r, r-faq

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [detecting operating system in R (e.g. for adaptive .Rprofile files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463087/detecting-operating-system-in-r-e-g-for-adaptive-rprofile-files)
>   [How can I determine in R what platform I'm running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919621/how-can-i-determine-in-r-what-platform-im-running-on)

Is there a primitive function in R that will return information about the system on which R is running? I am concerned primarily with the OS, but any other data could be helpful.

Comment: Looks like duplicate [detecting operating system in R (e.g. for adaptive .Rprofile files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463087/detecting-operating-system-in-r-e-g-for-adaptive-rprofile-files)

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919621/how-can-i-determine-in-r-what-platform-im-running-on/3922058#3922058

Answer (score 64, accepted):

use `Sys.info()` for all information about the system, `Sys.info()['sysname']` gives you the OS.

`R.Version()` gives you the version of R, including which architecture you're running (32bit - i386 - versus 64bit - x64 - ).

`R.home()` and `system.file(package="xxx")` give you information of the location of the root resp. the package files.

Comment: Would you change `Sys.info()$sysname` to `Sys.info()['sysname']`? The former will throw the error "Error in Sys.info()$sysname : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: @Jonathan true, I should've checked

Comment: That change is quite possibly more recent than the answer...  I think R tightened that post 2.13 or so.

Answer (score 50):

Here are three ways:

```
> .Platform$OS.type
[1] "unix"
> version$os ## or R.version$os
[1] "linux-gnu"
> Sys.info()["sysname"]
sysname 
"Linux"
```

Take a look at `?Sys.info` for some details and provisos.