# Is there an R constant for the OS' dynamic libraries file extension?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, file-extension

Or, generally speaking, is there a portable way to determine whether a file is a `.so/.dll/.dylib` using built-in `R` functions?

I simply refuse to believe that there isn't a more portable way than checking `file_ext()` with a case-statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the section on [`dyn.load`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#dyn_002eload-and-dyn_002eunload) in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual: `.Platform$dynlib.ext`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I obviously just overlooked that section -.-

Answer (score 0):

I think checking the extension is fine, but an alternative is to determine which platform you are one. You can do that with `Sys.info()`, more specifically `Sys.info()['sysname']`, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747715/how-to-check-the-os-within-r). For example, on my system:

```
> Sys.info()['sysname']
 sysname 
"Darwin"
```

Shows that I work on a Mac OS system. Linux users see `Linux`, and windows users presumable `Windows`.