# Check if OS is Solaris

Tags: r

I have the need to check logically if a computer's operating system is Solaris.  In other words I need a way to check if the operating system is Solaris, if so return `TRUE`, if not return `FALSE`.  I can easily check if an OS is Windows, Mac, Linux because I have access to these systems what `type` (e.g., "unix", "windows") to search for as this info is commonly google-able.  Something along the lines of:

```
.Platform$OS.type == "unix"
.Platform$OS.type == "windows"
```

works and there are other approaches well documented on SO (e.g., `Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows"`).  In my search of SO and Google I was led to many questions regarding Windows, Mac, Linux but no way to specifically to determine if the OS is Solaris.  For instance this link, which leads to other similar questions it duplicates, addresses determining the OS but not a logical check if Solaris.

[How to check the OS within R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747715/how-to-check-the-os-within-r)

**How can I programmatically determine if a computer's OS is Solaris?**

I may need to be more specific about what forms os Solaris I'm interested in (I'm not sure because I know very little about the OS).  Of particular interest are the Solaris systems used in CRAN checks:

1. r-patched-solaris-x86
2. r-patched-solaris-sparc

Comment: Are you implying that `Sys.info()['sysname']` gives a different value for different flavors of Solaris? Or that the information given is too general?

Comment: No basically I need to check if Solaris is the operating system and give a `TRUE` or `FALSE` answer.

Comment: So you are asking what exact string returned by `Sys.info()['sysname']` corresponds to `solaris`?

Comment: @merlin2011 Precisely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Digging into the C code that `Sys.info` uses, it ends up with a call to `sys/utsname.h`, which should be defined for most Unix-like systems ([and is indeed part of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/uname.html)).

Looking at [this website](http://www.ico.aha.ru/h/unix_system_crash_dump_analyze/0131493868_ch12lev1sec3.html), it seems like Solaris uses **SunOS** as the `utsname`. Here is a copy just in case that link dies:

```
The utsname macro
We've already seen one macro in use on a Solaris 2 system, utsname. 
As a refresher, here is how we called the utsname macro ...
Figure 12-1 Using the utsname macro

...
utsname:        sys  SunOS
```

Also, the [Wikipedia article on `uname`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) clearly states that the system name for all Solaris systems is **SunOS**.

So, just for completeness, you could easily `grep` for this in a function:

```
is.solaris<-function()
  grepl('SunOS',Sys.info()['sysname'])
```

Comment: I think that's it but have no way to test.  I'll see if I can get Solaris for Virtual box.

Comment: I have Solaris 11 on VirtualBox and can confirm that `Sys.info()['sysname']` returns `"SunOS"`

Comment: The string used in the CRAN description (http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_flavors.html) appears to be part of `R.Version()$platform`. The documentation describes that as being " A triplet of the form CPU-VENDOR-OS, as determined by the configure script.". I wonder if there's some other way to access the vendor piece.

Comment: @Ben I looked for your contact info to discuss an issue of list but couldn't find it.  If you could email me (see [qdap maintainer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html) info) I'd appreciate it.  I built Solaris 11 on virtual box on a Win 7 machine but can't get R up an running.  Any guidance on how you did it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tyler, I've posted details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24094964/1036500) ([this is me](http://faculty.washington.edu/bmarwick/))