# New line constant

Tags: r

Is there a new line constant that's platform independent in R?  I'm used to C# and there's `Environment.NewLine` which will return `\r\n` on windows and `\n` otherwise.  Searching turned up nothing, but I assume there has to be something somewhere so that scripts can be platform independent.

Related question: Is there a way to detect the platform a script is running on? This could be useful to know for other reasons (which I haven't thought of yet).

EDIT: Here's why I'm asking.  I'm downloading files from an FTP server, but want to get a list of files and only download files that are on the server that don't exist locally.  Here's how I'm getting the list of files:

```
filesonserver <- unlist(strsplit(getURL(basePath, ftp.use.epsv=F, dirlistonly=T), "\n"))
```

On windows, the files are separated by `\r\n`.  On my mac (where I'm currently working), they're separated by `\n`.  I was looking for a way to make this platform independent.  I haven't tried just separating by `\n` on windows, which might work.  There might also be a way to get the list of files as a vector without having to split them, which would avoid this entirely...

Comment: For the platform info, how about `R.Version()$platform` or `sessionInfo()$platform`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747715/how-to-check-the-os-within-r

Comment: Generally you shouldn't have to worry about newlines. R handles a lot of the complexity of reading text for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the initial question appears to be there isn't a new line constant like C# has.  But it doesn't matter in my case, as the comments pointed out.  It didn't occur to me until after I edited in the details that I probably didn't need to worry about it.  Splitting by `\n` works fine on windows, even though the string containing the files names returned by `getURL()` is split by `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The package `tryCatchLog` has a function `determine.platform.NewLine()`:

- https://cran.r-project.org/package=tryCatchLog
- https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog/blob/master/R/platform_newline.R

If you consequently use this string instead of hard-coded "\n" your new lines will work platform-independently.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548414/4468078