# Paste and print do not produce windows new line codes (with carriage return in R strings)

Tags: r, newline

I am simply pasting two strings but the created new line is not platform specific but always "\n".

I was expecting that the new line is converted to the platform specific code(s) where R is running:

```
charToRaw(paste0("a", "\n", "b"))
[1] 61 0a 62
```

I would expect

```
[1] 61 0d 0a 62
```

on Windows and

```
[1] 61 0a 62
```

on all other platforms.

How can I achieve this without explicitly using the correct platform-specific new line code(s)?

PS: I do not want to hard code "\r\n" to stay platform-independent...

See also: [New line constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962383/4468078)

**Edit 1:** Even when I print the string the "\n" is not converted to "\r\n" on Windows: `charToRaw(print(paste0("a", "\n", "b")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of your assumption is flawed.

You are using a literal `"\n"` and hoping that R will infer that you want to make it `"\r\n"`. If this were the case, then it would be impossible (or indeed very tricky) for R on windows to create a non-CRLF document for non-windows uses.

I am not recommending you install `data.table`'s package, but its `fwrite` function uses this to determine what each line's ending should be:

```r
str(formals(data.table::fwrite))
# Dotted pair list of 23
# ...truncated...
#  $ eol         : language if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "\r\n" else "\n"
# ...truncated...
```

I suggest you use something like this in your code:

```r
EOL <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "\r\n" else "\n"
charToRaw(paste0("a", EOL, "b"))
# [1] 61 0d 0a 62
```

On linux, this works out to be

```r
EOL <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "\r\n" else "\n"
charToRaw(paste0("a", EOL, "b"))
# [1] 61 0a 62
```

as one would hope/expect.

Comment: THX, this is indeed what I am doing currently but I am still wondering why R seems to be completely new line agnostic (or I am blind to see the solution ;-)

Comment: R is not always agnostic, though it appears inconsistent at times. I agree that similar to `.Platform$file.sep`, it would seem logical to have `.Platform$eol` (sounds like a really simple/good PR for R-devel). The hard part would be convincing R-core that it should be *used* in base functions. For instance, `formals(writeLines)$sep` is hard-coded to `"\n"` on both windows and linux, perhaps it should be either a global option or default to a platform-specific value. (I for one dislike CRLF, but I recognize that is far from a universal preference.)

Comment: I have mailed a question at r-devel: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-July/079802.html

Comment: From [Duncan's comment](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-July/079803.html), using `file("filename", open="w")` and `open="wb"` (arguments to `writeLines(..., con=file(...))`) produce CRLF and CR files (on windows), respectively. In linux it produces CR both times. Not sure if that's a help or just the less-convenient way you know about and are trying to shortcut.