# How do I Write files to desktop in Mac or Windows environment in R

Tags: r, directory, working-directory

I'm familiar with the the commands `file.path()` and the new `here()` package in R to make working with collaborators and different OS environments. But I'm afraid I can't figure out how to write a script that would save a basic .csv file to the user's desktop, regardless of whether the user is using a mac or OS system.

Basically, this is a setup script for a tutorial I am giving. I would like to send this to students before-hand so that they install the necessary packages. I would like to check that this has worked so my idea is to have them write out a csv file with the names of the installed packages. A version of the code is below. Could I use something like `Sys.info()` to tell if it is running on a Mac or PC and construct an `ifelse()` command?

```
#Necessary libraries
to.install<-c('tidyverse')

#Packages that have not been installed    
new.packages <- to.install[!(to.install %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]

#If there are packages that must be installed, this installs them
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages, repos='http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/')

#Save installed packages in out
out<-to.install[to.install %in% installed.packages()[,'Package']]

#Check
out

#Write out to desktop.  How do I do this in platform independent way?
#write.csv(out, '~/Desktop/test.csv')
#library(here)
#here()
```

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747715/how-to-check-the-os-within-r