# detecting operating system in R (e.g. for adaptive .Rprofile files)

Tags: r, operating-system

I was wondering how to automatically detect operating system in R, for example to place things in the .Rprofile.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096473/r-determine-if-a-script-is-running-in-windows-or-linux but the answers below are more complete.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm not sure about using `Sys.info()` since the help page says it is not implemented on all R platforms; maybe use `.Platform` instead?  `?.Platform` has a lot of useful information, since:

> ‘.Platform’ is a list with some
>   details of the platform under which R
>   was built.  This provides means to
>   write OS-portable R code.

It also seems the packages included with R use `.Platform` *much* more frequently than `Sys.info`.

```
josh: /c/R/R-2.12.0-src/src/library
> grep ".Platform" */R/* | wc -l
144
josh: /c/R/R-2.12.0-src/src/library
> grep ".Platform\$OS.type" */R/* | wc -l
99
josh: /c/R/R-2.12.0-src/src/library
> grep "Sys.info" */R/* | wc -l
4
```

Answer (score 117):

```
switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
Windows= {print("I'm a Windows PC.")},
Linux  = {print("I'm a penguin.")},
Darwin = {print("I'm a Mac.")})
```

Since it took me more than a trivial amount of time to sort this out, I thought other would benefit as well.

Regards,

- Brian

Answer (score 6):

```
> Sys.info()
                                      sysname 
                                      "Linux" 
                                      release 
                          "2.6.32-26-generic" 
                                      version 
"#48-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 24 09:00:03 UTC 2010"
```

Comment: There's also `R.version$os` but `Sys.info()` is better for testing against.

Comment: @Richie can you expand on why Sys.info() is better?

Comment: The help page for `R.version` says "Do not use `R.version$os` to test the platform the code is running on: use `.Platform$OS.type` instead."  Annoyingly, it doesn't mention the suitability of `Sys.info()`.

Answer (score 5):

Since `Sys.info()` and `.Platform$OS.type` produce differing results depending upon which OS is running, I searched some more and found the following function at https://www.r-bloggers.com/identifying-the-os-from-r/

```
get_os <- function(){
  sysinf <- Sys.info()
  if (!is.null(sysinf)){
    os <- sysinf['sysname']
    if (os == 'Darwin')
      os <- "osx"
  } else { ## mystery machine
    os <- .Platform$OS.type
    if (grepl("^darwin", R.version$os))
      os <- "osx"
    if (grepl("linux-gnu", R.version$os))
      os <- "linux"
  }
  tolower(os)
}
```