# In R, what's the canonical way to detect if the OS is 64-bit?

Tags: r, operating-system, 64-bit

Some possibilities include:

```
Sys.info()["machine"] == "x86-64"
.Platform$r_arch == "x64"
version$arch == "x86_64"
```

Is there any reason to prefer one method over another?

Related: [detecting operating system in R (e.g. for adaptive .Rprofile files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463087/detecting-operating-system-in-r-e-g-for-adaptive-rprofile-files)

Comment: I believe those will all fail for at least PowerPC and Itanium 64 bit architecture. `grep`ing `.Platform$r_arch` for "64" might work for most architectures, but why bother when DWin's provided the answer.

Comment: Would probably also fail for Solaris builds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually none of those methods would be canonical, which I take to mean "what would Brian Ripley say". Try this:

```
?.Machine
```

sizeof.pointer........the number of bytes in a C SEXP type. Will be 4 on 32-bit builds and 8 on 64-bit builds of R.

```
 64bit <- .Machine$sizeof.pointer == 8
 64bit
 #[1] TRUE
```

As for your nominations only one of them returns TRUE on my machine:

```
> Sys.info()["machine"] == "x86-64"
machine 
  FALSE 
> .Platform$r_arch == "x64"
[1] FALSE
> version$arch == "x86_64"
[1] TRUE
```