# How do you make a package differentially install on windows?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm developing this package, which works fine on Unix and Mac. It uses the `parallel` package, so I was expecting issues with Windows, since I have some code using fork clusters.
Lo an' behold, Windows did not disapoint...

Is there a way I can somehow have the installation check what OS it is under and get a different version of the affected functions ? 
Checking for the OS inside the affected code is also a possible option, but seems less clean.

I'm sure there is a way to do this since `parallel` itself has to do it, but I haven't been able to find out how. When I look into its functions' code, there are only stops/warnings for windows-related stuff, indicating that the OS check is done during install at latest.

Comment: Perhaps use some site that tests your build on each OS type? Say continuous integration?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463087/detecting-operating-system-in-r-e-g-for-adaptive-rprofile-files

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start for checking within the code/functions. Any ideas on setting this up for a conditional install process ?